# How to make a 5-minute down counter using flip-flops?

Tags: digital-logic, counter

Is it possible to make a 5-minute counter that counts from 5:00 to 0:00 and restarts? How many flip-flops (bits) would I need?

Comment: More or less, depending on whether you want seconds to count down in steps of 1, or going straight from *5:00* to *0:00* is OK.

Comment: What is the frequency of your clock source?

Comment: There's an article that mentions "5 minute" on it regarding a [CMOS CD4060 device](https://www.coolcircuit.com/timer-4060/) that may be helpful to read. Just a thought.

Answer (score 3):

5 minutes is 300 seconds.  You don't specify a clock frequency in your post, so as others have said, let's assume a 1 Hz clock signal.  You don't say if you need to show the count in a typical digital display.

If yes, then you will need 10 count stages, with one flipflop each.  That is 4 for the seconds units (0 - 9), three for the seconds tens (0 - 5), and three for the minutes units (0 - 5).  To this you have to add gating to preset the minutes counters with 101 (5 decimal) when the overall count reaches 0:00.  You also will need decoders and drivers for the display.

If no, then you will need 9 count stages in a simple binary counter, plus gating to preset the counter to 100101100 (300 decimal) when it counts down to zero.  Note that only 4 of the counter stages need preset logic.

Something else you don't specify is what happens when the count reaches 0.  If the counter sits at 0:00 for one full second, and then restarts at 5:00 for one full second before decrementing to 4:59, the total time period for one cycle is 5:01, not 5:00.  For an exact 5:00 cycle time, either the counter (and display?) sits at 0:00 for one second, and then restarts with 4:59, or it restarts instantly when it reaches 0:00, jumping to 5:00.  In this case, the display will flicker 0:00 for less than a microsecond, too fast to perceive.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a 1 Hz source, the needed bits can be calculated via:

Bits = log2(seconds)

In your case log2(300) = 8.22, since you can't split bits, you should use 9 bits.

Reset to 5:00 should be doable with flipflops.

Comment: Note that this answer is a simple binary counter.  It will need extensive logic to decode the count into the 12-bit BCD format (or 21 bits of seven-segment signals) necessary to drive a digital display.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a 1 Hz clock (no FFs for pre-scaler), 9 bits/FFs are minimum to count down 5×60(+1) seconds one by one.

Counting in binary and converting to (7-segment/possibly even via) decimal is not mandatory;
In a GAL implementation, I'd count in the required output code directly for 3+3+4 FFs for decimal or 6+6+7 FFs for 7-segment.